# Download file to temp dir in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to download a file from the internet to my temp directory.

This is what I have so far:

```
HRESULT hr;
LPCTSTR Url = _T("linkhere"), File = _T("C:\\test.exe");
hr = URLDownloadToFile (0, Url, File, 0, 0);
```

This is working fine.

How do I save the file to the temp directory (using GetTempPath)

Comment: `File = _T("C:\\temp\\test.exe")`? Or are you asking about [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: I'm asking about GetTempPath. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since the directory that's used to store temporary files is configurable, you shouldn't hardcode its path into the application. Instead, use [GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to ask for the path and then use the result as a prefix, meaning you can simply append "temp.exe" to it.

(Btw, you can use "/" instead "\", since constantly having to escape backslashes is both tedious and error prone. For example, instead of "some\random\path\", you write "some/random/path/").